# Terminate Worklow in SharePoint Office 365 Deleting associated tasks

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks

I have a Sharepoint 2013 workflow made in SPD in Sharepoint Online, it works just great, but when the workflow is canceled manually, it doesn´t delete its associated tasks, How can I configure my workflow in order to deleted its associated tasks when it be canceled? I dont really find information about this.

is there any action or procedure which I can get advantage of to do it, that allows me to activate another workflow for delete the tasks or any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow tasks won`t delete the on cancellation of workflow. You have to delete these manually or automate if this process one of the following ways.

1. Create a Powershell script and run this when required.
2. Schedule this PowerShell to run daily.
3. Create a site workflow to run daily.

[cleanup tasks from workflows and deleted items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87964/cleanup-tasks-from-workflows-and-deleted-items)

I haven`t tested this but found an useful solution they have for on premises but it may helpful to get started with an approach.